# Hiding Decimal Results from PGF Output

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have this `\foreach` statement which results in even numbers with decimals. I would like to omit or hide the decimal from the results. How can this be done simply? I have seen a few answers to much more complicated queries, but I can find a way to marry those solutions to my question.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{snakes,backgrounds,arrows,decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
%
%
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw   [<-]    (0,7)       --      (0,3.8)
              node    [at start,left]         {$A.$};     
                \draw   [->]    (-0.2,4)    --      (3,4);
                \foreach [evaluate=\y as \yeval using \y*10] \y in {4,5,6,7}
                    \draw   (-2pt,\y)   --  (2pt,\y)
                    node    [anchor=east,left]  at (0,\y) {$\small \yeval$};


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
%
%
\end{document}
```

Comment: You may use `int(\y*10)` instead of `\y*10`...

Comment: I don't know tikz, but changing `\y*10` to `\y0` will give desired labels.  But I don't know if it breaks the plot in other ways.

Comment: I would use the PGF number parser to print the number. If you say `{\small \pgfmathprintnumber{\yeval}}`, the number will be automatically rounded. This macro allows you to control the number output very flexibly, without changing the calculation of the value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Remarks

You could make use of PGF's `\pgfmathprintnumber`. Review section 66 of the PGF Manual for further information. I also cleaned up the code a little.

## Implementation

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[<-] (0,7) node[right] {$A.$} -- (0,3.8);     
    \draw[->] (-0.2,4) -- (3,4);
    \foreach[evaluate=\y as \yeval using \y*10] \y in {4,5,6,7} {
        \draw (-2pt,\y) -- (2pt,\y) node[left] at (0,\y) {\small $\pgfmathprintnumber{\yeval}$};
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## Output

> [image: out]